# Variables in a for loop are not being assigned in R

Tags: r

I have a code that involves manipulating a series of matrices while conducting a series of matrix multiplications and summation on them.

Since those actions have to be made in iterations, I cannot avoid using a for loop. My problem is that although while testing my operations individually things seem to work. Within the loop  simple variable assignments like A<-B are being ignored.

I must be missing something here, I have checked this on both RGui and Rstudio and the problem repeats itself. I'm rather new to R and this is probably a formatting problem I seem to miss. The loop code is below. Variable assignments like RevisedCoeff in the second line are being ignored and the closing } brackets are being reported as unexpected. CTRL+F shows no second appearance of closing curly brackets } in the whole code, the same goes for the { opening curly brackets. This is the only loop in my code. The code runs perfectly up to that loop.

```
for (i in 1:length(ScndaryCoeff)){ 

  RevisedCoeff<-Coefficents

      RevisedCoeff[-grep(paste(ScndaryCoeff[i]),rownames(RevisedCoeff))
         ,-grep(paste(ScndaryCoeff[i]),colnames(RevisedCoeff))]=0


  RevisedMinmat<-Minmat

  RevisedMaxmat<-Maxmat

# Revised minimum d
RevisedMinmat[grep(paste(ScndaryCoeff[i])
               ,rownames(RevisedMinmat))]
<-MinScndaryGDPVals[i]

# revised maximum d  

RevisedMaxmat[grep(paste(ScndaryCoeff[i])
               ,rownames(RevisedMaxmat))]
<-MaxScndaryGDPVals[i]

print(RevisedMinmat)
print(RevisedMaxmat)

#getting Secondary GDP

ScndGDPMinmat<-RevisedCoeff%*%RevisedMinmat
ScndGDPMaxmat<-RevisedCoeff%*%RevisedMaxmat

print(ScndGDPMinmat)
print(ScndGDPMaxmat)

# vector of secondary GDP Values

MinGDPVector[[i]]<-ScndGDPMinmat[grep(paste(ScndaryCoeff[i])
                                  ,rownames(ScndGDPMinmat))]
MaxGDPVector[[i]]<-ScndGDPMaxmat[grep(paste(ScndaryCoeff[i])
                                  ,rownames(ScndGDPMaxmat))]

#vector of secondary GDP matrices

ScndaryGDPMinList[[i]]<-ScndGDPMinmat
ScndaryGDPMaxList[[i]]<-ScndGDPMaxmat



# Summation of indirect GDP's and removal of direct GDP

Mindex<- -grep(paste(ScndaryCoeff[i])
           ,rownames(FinalMinMat))

FinalMinMat<-FinalMinMat[Mindex]+
ScndaryGDPMinList[[i]][-grep(paste(ScndaryCoeff[i])
                           ,rownames(ScndaryGDPMinList[[i]]))]
print(FinalMinMat)

Maxdex<- -grep(paste(ScndaryCoeff[i])
           ,rownames(FinalMaxMat))

FinalMaxMat<-FinalMaxMat[Maxdex]+
ScndaryGDPMaxList[[i]][-grep(paste(ScndaryCoeff[i])
                           ,rownames(ScndaryGDPMaxList[[i]]))] 


print(FinalMaxMat)

  # adding original GDP rows from starting GDP matrices

 counter<-grep(paste(ScndaryCoeff[i]),rownames(MinGDP))

  ifelse(counter=1
     ,FinalMinMat<-rbind(MinGDP[counter],FinalMinMat)
     ,FinalMinMat<-rbind(FinalMinMat[(1:(counter-1))]
                         ,MinGDP[counter]
                         ,FinalMinMat[-(1:(counter-1))]))
  print(FinalMinMat)

  ifelse(counter=1
     ,FinalMxaMat<-rbind(MaxGDP[counter],FinalMaxMat)
     ,FinalMaxMat<-rbind(FinalMaxMat[(1:(counter-1))]
                         ,MaxGDP[counter]
                         ,FinalMaxMat[-(1:(counter-1))]))

  print(FinalMaxMat)
}
```

Comment: Missing `}` means that you probably have a missing or additional parenthesis somewhere. Try to define `i` and run the lines in the loops one-by-one

Answer (score 1):

If this is your actual formatting,

```
RevisedMinmat[grep(paste(ScndaryCoeff[i])
               ,rownames(RevisedMinmat))]
<-MinScndaryGDPVals[i]
```

then it is a syntax error.  Since the first two lines form a complete statement, the third line is treated on its own, and it's not legal to have an assignment to nothing.

When I do something similar:

```
x <- -1
for (i in 1:10) {
    x
    <- i
}
```

I get these errors:

```
> x <- -1
> for (i in 1:10) {
+   x
+   <- i
Error: unexpected assignment in:
"        x
        <-"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

So I suspect you had more than just the `unexpected '}'` error.

Comment: I see and except,  but even if this is true, and I have  changed it. The problem begins with the first line in the loop which is a properly formatted assignment that works outside the loop . I did try your correction all over the code. The problem persists though with the same error, as I expected. I again mention - no other curled parenthesis in the code but the pair seen in the code extract .

Comment: Did you try to run line by line the code in the loop? Which error do you get?

Comment: If you have a syntax error in the for loop, none of the loop will run, and any earlier opening brace will be forgotten, leading to another syntax error at the end of the loop.

Comment: You should update your question to include the corrected version of the code that still generates the error.  We can't help you if we don't know what you are running.

Comment: Hi everyone and thank you for your replies. I did a combination of both advice given here. That is fixing the syntax of some of the assignments and running the loop separately. This has solved the assignments issue. After that I copy pasted the previously written code before the loop creating a new Rstudio editor window. The issue has been solved. I don't know what made the previous piece of code (that's supposed to be identical) not to accept assignments. Maybe an unnoticed  surplus piece of code or a badly written comment. But thank to your advice I can now go on from this issue.